# Request headers are not parsing correctly using Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, http-headers, nginx-config

I just created a new Ubuntu instance on AWS. After installing Nginx request headers are not parsing correctly whenever I'm requesting using a device(Android/iOS).

Using postman I am able to get headers on node app but whenever I try with the device it's showing undefined. Using public DNS I'm able to get headers so I'm expecting that issue is with Nginx configuration.

Here are the Headers which I'm receiving on my Node js app from postman and android device respectively:

// using Postman

```
{ host: '<Host>',
 'x-real-ip': '<id-address>',
 connection: 'upgrade',
 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
 'postman-token': <token>,
 authorization: <auth_token>,
 'content-type': 'application/json',
 'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/6.2.5',
 accept: '*/*',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate' }

// using android device
 { host: '<host>',
  'x-real-ip': '<ip-address>',
  connection: 'upgrade',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'user-agent': 'okhttp/3.10.0' }
```

As you can see in device headers **authorization** is not present so it is showing undefined.

Nginx configuration:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
server {
if ($host = <host>) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen [::]:80;
listen 80;
server_name <host>;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502 http_503 http_504;
}
}
```

Please help me with this.

Headers coming from iOS device

```
http://<request-url>/?is_new_device=false&device_id=A2F6C479-2C52-4A43-ADB6-D86771431B5A
 ▿ url : Optional<URL>
  ▿ some : http://<request-url>/?is_new_device=false&device_id=A2F6C479-2C52-4A43-D86771431B5A
   - _url : http://<request-url>/?is_new_device=false&device_id=A2F6C479-2C52-4A43-D86771431B5A
 - cachePolicy : 0
 - timeoutInterval : 60.0
 - mainDocumentURL : nil
 - networkServiceType : __C.NSURLRequestNetworkServiceType
 - allowsCellularAccess : true
 ▿ httpMethod : Optional<String>
  - some : "GET"
 ▿ allHTTPHeaderFields : Optional<Dictionary<String, String>>
  ▿ some : 2 elements
   ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "Authorization"
    - value : "Bearer google-oauth2 <token>"
   ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "User-Agent"
    - value : "Impact/3.5.16 iPhone9,3 iOS/13.3 CFNetwork/1121.2.2 Darwin/19.2.0"
 - httpBody : nil
 - httpBodyStream : nil
 - httpShouldHandleCookies : true
 - httpShouldUsePipelining : false
```

Comment: Can you add more explanation of your flow, are you saying you are not using jnginx when request via node app?

Comment: Also I think you should change `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` to `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: @Sohan yes.. every request is coming through Nginx to Node app.. Changed with $host.. not working

Comment: You are not using any proxy_pass right? Also there are no custom hearders in response?

Comment: What is your proxy_pass url? why i cannot see that when you are using above headers

Comment: yes, I'm using the proxy pass and authorization headers

Comment: Why I cannot see in nginx configuration?

Comment: @Sohan backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:<port>;
}

Comment: Can you add log from android device with request headers? Or, just add nginx log and print all request headers in it.

Comment: @Talkerbox I added headers coming from iOS device in the question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solved by removing the below code from the Nginx configuration. Headers are not parsing when I redirect requests from Http to https.

```
if ($host = <host>) 
{ return 301 https://$host$request_uri; } # managed by Certbot
```